# Issue with Button component

Tags: unity, component-based

When I add a Button component, it looks like this:

[image]

Normally, it should look like this:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the top of the window where you see that, you should see a tab named 'Debug'. Normally the tab would be named 'Inspector'. The difference is that at some point you clicked the little menu drop down to the top right of that and switched to Debug mode instead of Normal mode.

Switch back to Normal and it should appear the way you're expecting.

More details here: [Inspector Options](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html)

Comment: Ah, fancy. I didn't know about that option.

Comment: Sorry Chris, the OP here is a duplicate account created by someone that is banned. Unfortunately this user doesn't care about wasting other people's time. This answer will not be accepted.

Comment: C'est la StackExchange. :) Too bad the question isn't framed such that others will find it useful, though.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question as much as you like